# QT: Frameless window not animating

Tags: c++, qt, qmainwindow

i need some help for my current project named "RibbonUI".
As the project name suggest, i want to implement the MS RibbonUI like in Office 2013 in QT - most stuff is working nice but i need to know something about the `Qt::FramelessWindowHint`.

I have subclassed the `QMainWindow` and added the enum value `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` to override the default window decoration. The buttons are implemented fine - i can minimize, maximize and close my frameless window, but the window is not animated when minimizing/maximizing/restore the window from the taskbar.

Do i have to implement the animation by myself or can i use a window manager hint or something else?

Here is a screenshot from my current work:
[image]

Comment: What version of Qt do you use? There were a bug - https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-17548, but seems that it's not related to your question.

Comment: I use QT 5.2.x, my app is not affected by this bug. Problem is only the window, which isnt animated when minimizing/maximizing/restored from taskbar.

Comment: I understood now. Windows OS does not animate windows that has no system borders. So you should do animation by yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Dimitry. Is there a way to get the target "icon position" on the taskbar? I need this to animate the geometry of the window

Comment: You should use WinAPI for that

Comment: OMG ... WinAPI? Oh nooooo - i want to support more platforms but Windows OS xD Thanks, i'll take a look at this **** API :)

Comment: And OS X api for Mac OS... Such window managment is platform-specific.